# Logging specific application's actions with adb

Tags: android, logging, adb

I've searched through Google's dev docs and some Android debugging tutorials, but I couldn't find any information on logging some specific information from installed applications.
I need to see all the files the application has accessed, all the SMS and call activity it made.
Something like this online security tool, https://anubis.iseclab.org, but on a local PC with a physical device.

Is there any way to retrieve this information from a device?